# IONIC/AngularJs on IOS - wrong innerWidth and innerHeight when changing screen orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

It's my first time asking a question on stackoverflow, so i'll try to be as specific as I can. Thanks for your help.

Currently I'm developing an application for Androïd and IOS with Angular/IONIC solution.

Actually I've developed a service using cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 1.4.2 version plugin to change the orientation of my screen for some views. In fact, that work perfectly on both OS. But I also need when it's done, to catch the width and height of my device.

So there is my problem. On Android everything works, but on IOS, it looks like when I change the orientation I catch always the old values. (if I change for a landscape, I catch the previous portrait orientation values).

I tried different algorythm like the more simple : change the orientation and when it's done catch the values.

Currently I'm trying with a watcher, for the same result.

Here is my code :

```
class WindowService extends Service {
constructor($resource,$config, $window, Watcher) {
    'ngInject';
    super();

    this.orientations = {
        1:"portrait",
        2:"landscape"
    }

    //imported library
    this.md = new MobileDetect($window.navigator.userAgent);
    // if it's a tablet Android, md.tablet() != null && md.os() == 'AndroidOS'
    // if it's an iPad md.tablet() == 'iPad'
    // if it's an iPhone md.mobile() == 'iPhone'
    // if it's an Android phone, md.phone() != null && md.os() == 'AndroidOS'
    console.log("md > ", this.md.mobile());

    this.maxHeight = "100vh";
    this.maxWidth = "100vw";
    if (this.isAndroid()){
        this.maxHeight = $window.innerHeight + "px";
        this.maxWidth = $window.innerWidth + "px";

        this.maxHeightWatcher = Watcher.watch(() => $window.innerHeight, innerHeight => {
            this.maxHeight = $window.innerHeight + "px";
            this.maxWidth = $window.innerWidth + "px";
        });
    }
}

setOrientation(){
    this.invoke(($window) => {
        if ($window.screen.unlockOrientation){
            $window.screen.unlockOrientation();
            if ((this.md.phone() != null && this.md.os() == 'AndroidOS') || this.md.mobile() == 'iPhone'){
                $window.screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
            }else if ((this.md.tablet() != null && this.md.os() == 'AndroidOS') || this.md.tablet() == 'iPad'){
                $window.screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
            }else {
                $window.screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
            }
        }
    });
}

//THIS S THE FUNCTION I CALL
changeOrientation(orientationId){
    this.invoke(($window) => {
        this.lockScreenOrientation($window, orientationId).then(res => {
            console.log("changeOrientation > ", res);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("changeOrientation > ", err);
        });
    });
}

lockScreenOrientation($window, orientationId){
    if (this.orientations[orientationId] != undefined){
        if (this.orientations[orientationId] != $window.screen.orientation){
            if ($window.screen.unlockOrientation){
                    $window.screen.unlockOrientation();
                    console.log("lockOrientation > ", $window.screen.lockOrientation(this.orientations[orientationId]));
                    return Promise.resolve(this.orientations[orientationId]);
            }else{
                return Promise.reject("[ERROR] cordova-plugin-screen-orientation hadn't been loaded.")
            }
        }else{
            return Promise.resolve(this.orientations[orientationId]);
        }
    }else{
        return Promise.reject("[ERROR] The orientation specified is Unknown.")
    }
}

getDevice(){
    if ((this.md.phone() != null && this.md.os() == 'AndroidOS')){
        return "Android Smartphone";
    }else if (this.md.mobile() == 'iPhone'){
        return "iPhone";
    }else if ((this.md.tablet() != null && this.md.os() == 'AndroidOS')){
        return "Android Tablet";
    }else if (this.md.tablet() == 'iPad'){
        return "iPad";
    }else
        return "Unknown";
}

isSmartphone(){
    if ((this.md.phone() != null && this.md.os() == 'AndroidOS') || this.md.mobile() == 'iPhone'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

isTablet(){
    if ((this.md.tablet() != null && this.md.os() == 'AndroidOS') || this.md.tablet() == 'iPad')
        return true;
    return false;
}

isIOS() {
    if (this.md.mobile() == 'iPhone' || this.md.tablet() == 'iPad')
        return true;
    return false;
}

isAndroid() {
    if ((this.md.phone() != null && this.md.os() == 'AndroidOS')
        || (this.md.tablet() != null && this.md.os() == 'AndroidOS'))
        return true;
    return false;
}

getMaxHeight(){
    return this.maxHeight;
}

getMaxWidth(){
    return this.maxWidth;
}
```

}
Service.register(WindowService);

```
<ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false" ng-controller="HeaderController" style="height:{{view.maxHeight}};width: {{view.maxWidth}};"> 

    ....

</ion-side-menu-content>
```

The class Watcher is just an little extension of the basic watcher of angular. It works the same way.

[edit] Sorry I forgot to specify something : as you can see in the js code, in the constructor method, if it's IOS I just put 100vh fr the height and 100vw for the width. And I have the same result : the change from portrait to landscape keep the portrait size values.